# c++ Concatenate char arrays

Tags: c++, string, byte

I'm making a game, where the program automatically broadcasts that the user is online. A broadcast message would be made up of the following: 
1. byte: a value from 0 to 6
2-5. byte: an rgba color
6-... bytes: the user's name

The first 5 bytes are stored in `char buf_begin`, while the username is stored in `std::string username`.

I tried this:

```
std::string buf_begin_s(buf_begin);
std::string buf = buf_begin_s + username;

sendto(udp_br, buf.c_str(), sizeof(buf.c_str()), 0, (sockaddr *)&to, sizeof(to));
```

The problem is that the `buf` string doesn't contain 1-5. bytes, only the username.

Comment: No, not `sizeof(pointer)`. Try `strlen`, or `buf.length()`.

Comment: Since `buf` might contain `'\0'`, `strlen()` will not work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string buf_begin_s(buf_begin);
```

If, as you say, `buf_begin` is a 5-character buffer, and the first character could be 0, then when it is 0 `buf_begin_s` ends up to be an empty string. This constructor expects a C-style string that terminates with a `'\0'` character. If the first character in `buf` is a 0 byte, this will be the end of the story.

If none of the 5 characters in the buffer are 0, this results in undefined behavior, as the constructor plows ahead in the memory, looking for the `'\0'` byte.

This should probably be:

```
std::string buf_begin_s(buf_begin, buf_begin+5);
```

The `sendto()` call is also wrong:

```
sendto(udp_br, buf.c_str(), sizeof(buf.c_str()), 0, (sockaddr *)&to, sizeof(to));
```

Since `buf.c_str()` is a `const char *`, the third parameter will be `sizeof(const char *)`, or either 4 or 8, depending on whether this is a 32 or a 64 bit platform. No matter how much there's in the `buf`, `sizeof(buf.c_str())` will always be 4 or 8. This is obviously wrong.

This should simply be `buf.size()`.